# How to write a method to check if textbox inputted value is already inputted into another sql table?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

Hello I am fairly new to asp.net. I was wondering how to write a boolean method that will check the inputted textbox value and check to see if the input was already placed in another sql table. I have many sql tables that have foreign keys connecting them to one another.

For example say I have a table for all the customers the store gets and the primary key is customer id. Then I have another table that shows all the customers that come in only on Saturdays, one of the columns being customer id and there is a foreign key that connects the ids of the two tables together. If I am trying to add another customer to the list of customers that only comes on saturday how do I write a boolean method that will check textbox values to see if customer id already exists in the table with all the customers?

Answer (score -1):

1. There are multiple ways to solve this issue, you can write up like
   this --

   1) Add a custom validation on the page, which will do serverside
   validation -

   ```
   <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       runat="server" OnServerValidate="Text_Validate"   
       ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Customer Already exists.">
   ```

   2) on server side aspx.cs file, write up this validation method -

   ```
   protected void Text_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e) {      
       // make db connectivity code
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE FieldValue='TextBox1.text') {       
           e.IsValid = true; 
       } else {
           e.IsValid = false; 
       }
   }
   ```